# Select rows where number can be found in list

Tags: pandas

Given the following data

[image]

I hope to select the rows where `num` appears in `list`. In this case, it will select row 1 and row2, row 3 is not selected since `3` can't be found in `[4,5]`.

Following is the dataframe, how should we write the filter query?

```
cat1=pd.DataFrame({"num":[1,2,3],
                 "list":[[1,2,3],[3,2],[4,5]]})
```

Answer (score 4):

One possible solution with list comprehension, `zip` and `in` passed to [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = cat1[[a in b for a, b in zip(cat1.num, cat1.list)]]
```

Or solution with [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` for processing per rows:

```
df = cat1[cat1.apply(lambda x: x.num in x.list, axis=1)]
```

Or create `DataFrame` and test membership:

```
df = cat1[pd.DataFrame(cat1.list.tolist()).isin(cat1.num).any(axis=1)]
```

---

```
print (df)
   num       list
0    1  [1, 2, 3]
1    2     [3, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

A different solution if you are using pandas `.25` is using [`explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
cat1[cat1['num'].isin(cat1.explode('list1').query("num==list1").loc[:,'num'])]
```

---

```
   num      list1
0    1  [1, 2, 3]
1    2     [3, 2]
```